# Better way to group by on all select fields in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I am trying to provide a simple example of a real data warehouse schema, so please forgive me if tables are so naive and elementary.

Main table is called `Items` with `ItemName` as primary key:

[image: Items Table]

There are two other tables called `Properties` and `attributes` all with `id` column (auto identity) as primary key:

[image: Attributes]

[image: Properties]

**Question**: I want to query these tables like this:

```
SELECT 
    I.ItemName, A.AttributeName, I.Col1, I.Col2, I.Col3, I.Col4, 
    pForFilter.Property 
FROM 
    Items I 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    attributes A ON I.ItemName = A.ItemName 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Properties pForFilter On I.ItemName = pForFilter.ItemName 
GROUP BY 
    I.ItemName, A.AttributeName, I.Col1, I.Col2, I.Col3, I.Col4, 
    pForFilter.Property 
HAVING 
    pForFilter.Property = 'Prop1'
```

Here is the result:

[image: Results]

The real part of query is `I.Itemname`, `A.AttributeName` as distinct values, so a `GROUP BY` is added to simulate distinct values on these two fields. Please note that filtering is done based on `Property` column but I do not need property in the select list. Yet I need other fields of `Items` table as well (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) in the select list. My question is can I rewrite this query so that I won't have to group by on all these extra fields? Is the provided query efficient at all? If I have to use it, can I use indexes to improve the speed of my query and what index could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I get from the logic of your query, you are only interested in `'Prop1'` so you can just inner join to that. So, assuming that your items table doesn't have duplicates, then you only need to get the distinct ItemName, AttributeName combination. A query like this will give you what you need with so many columns in the `group by`

```
SELECT I.ItemName, attr.AttributeName, I.Col1,
       I.Col1, I.Col2, I.Col3, I.Col4, prop.Property
FROM Items I 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT p.ItemName, p.Property
                 FROM Properties p 
                 WHERE p.Property = 'Prop1'
                 GROUP BY p.ItemName, p.Property) prop
            ON I.ItemName = prop.ItemName
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.ItemName, A.AttributeName
                FROM Attributes A
                GROUP BY A.ItemName, A.AttributeName) attr
            ON I.ItemName = attr.ItemName
```

Comment: Combination of INNER JOIN and GROUP BY on the required fields was what I missed. Can I improve the speed using an index? Specially Items table has good amount of records, Properties may reach 1000 rows (which is negligible) and Attributes table can reach a million rows.

Comment: @YasserSobhdel, I don't claim perfect knowledge in indexing. But I think creating non-clustered indexes on joining columns might improve performance. see this article on suggestion on indexing http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/indexes-just-because-you-can-doesnt-mean-you-should/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't need to `GROUP` anything.

At first you want to find all items that have Property `Prop1`:

```
SELECT Properties.ItemName
FROM Properties
WHERE Properties.Property = 'Prop1'
```

It doesn't make sense to me to allow two rows with the same `ItemName` and `Property` in this table, so you should add a unique constraint for this pair of columns to make your intentions clear to programmers and to query optimizer. With this constraint in place there is no need for `GROUP BY` here.

Since you are going to filter by `Property`, I would add the following unique index to this table. It would enforce the constraint and help with searches. The order of columns in the index is important.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Properties] ON [dbo].[Properties]
(
    [Property] ASC,
    [ItemName] ASC
))
```

In fact, I would consider removing `ID` column from this table and making that unique index a primary key, especially if this `ID` is not used in many foreign keys. It also may be useful (for other possible queries) to add a second unique index to this table with these two columns listed in another order.

Similar thoughts apply to `Attributes` table. Once you clearly state that there can be only one row with the same `ItemName` and `AttributeName` in the `Attributes` table, no `GROUP BY` is necessary.

Your query becomes:

```
SELECT
    I.ItemName
    ,Attributes.AttributeName
    ,I.Col1
    ,I.Col2
    ,I.Col3
    ,I.Col4
FROM
    Items AS I
    INNER JOIN Properties ON Properties.ItemName = I.ItemName
    INNER JOIN Attributes ON Attributes.ItemName = I.ItemName
WHERE
    Properties.Property = 'Prop1'
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yet the structure of Data Warehouse is predetermined and I have to query some views. Those views are union of tables with the same name to which name of month is appended (i.e., SomeView_Jan, SomeView_Feb, ...)